# mutliple column with one foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### tableX

c1|c2|c1_y_id|c2_y_id

### tableY

id|value

c1_y_id and c2_y_id foreign key to tableY.

Here how to get c1 value;

```
Select value From tableX, tableY Where tableX.c1_y_id = tableY.id
```

I need to get c1 and c2's value only with one sql. Thanks for any advice

Comment: can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below SQL should work for your purpose

```
SELECT Y1.value AS c1_value
      ,Y2.value AS c2_value
  FROM tableX X
 INNER
  JOIN tableY Y1
    ON X.c1_y_id = Y1.id
 INNER
  JOIN tableY Y2
    ON X.c2_y_id = Y2.id
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thats cool, but actually there are 8 columns  :) I think 8 inner joins makes sql very slow.

Comment: I see only 2 in the question you posted.. if you indeed have 8 and all of them are linked to `tableY` the same way, then you may have to do this in multiple steps, instead of one sql statement if the above join approach does not work for you

Comment: can't we do it with some case or if combinaton in select statement ?

Comment: I think you could try that, but unsure if it would address your concern of performance...